# Has anyone produced a time series of the Gini coefficient to current political party?

Tags: economy, statistics, inequality

Has anyone ever done a global or regional time series of the [Gini coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient)* mapped against the current ideological faction** in power?

The more countries in the time series, the more informative the time series could be (by virtue of a larger sample size).

I'd love to know how strong the (presumably time delayed) correlation is.

<sub>* Or the rate of change of the coefficient.</sub> 
 <sub>** Along a classical left-right spectrum for simplicity and the existing over-abundance of dichotomic literature.</sub>

Comment: Good question. Obviously you have to be careful about extrapolating conclusions from a correlation like that, but that graph would be interesting. Mind you, because (at least in America) wealth inequality has been steadily rising for about half a century, I'm not sure you'd find a meaningful correlation.

Comment: More informative times series for countries with steadily rising values would be the rate of change of the coefficient, but that would require complex maths and extrapolations to make up for the lack of sufficiently granular data (e.g. tax returns/bank account balances are private so you need to extrapolate wealth through carefully selected market signals).

Comment: @Avi, how could you find a meaningful correlation in the USA at all? [In the last 30 years](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Combined--Control_of_the_U.S._House_of_Representatives_-_Control_of_the_U.S._Senate.png/800px-Combined--Control_of_the_U.S._House_of_Representatives_-_Control_of_the_U.S._Senate.png) 10 years a party has had control of all three branches.

Comment: "presumably time delayed" is the crux. Clinton benefitted economically from both Reagan's winning cold war and building up the military (by being able to spend a LOT less on defence) and from being in the right place and time to both benefit from dot-com economic boom AND escape the bust (which hurt Bush instead, despite being nothing caused by Bush). Plenty of actions have direct and indirect effect that are greatly time delayed, due to various economics factors.

Comment: Also, how do you deal with (what in US is a predominant state) of divided government? Both Bush and Reagan mostly dealt with D-dominated congress, Clinton vice versa. Or left+right coalitions?

Comment: @DVK, yeah, ultimately you have to look at the impact of specific policies and see who supported them.

Comment: @DVK It's possible (if unfortunate) that we would have to drop the USA and equivalent countries from any global time series; as the political system in these countries lack an exclusivity or primacy clause to condense concurrent implementation to a sole party or point upon an one-axis spectrum. Put simply, you might be right that a time series would be impossible in at least some countries since there isn't a "current" political faction in power, but rather a subtle and complicated interplay of explicitly and implicitly politicised government branches; each with different time-frames.

Comment: @Avi - that presupposes that you can accurately attribute impact. Not always possible, especially once you wise up to second and third order impacts.

Comment: How are people ensuring their samples aren't tampered with?? I'm thinking routing here. Telephonic, internet or otherwise.

Comment: Here is a scatter plot of Gini wealth coefficient versus economic freedom plotted for dozens of countries. https://www.flickr.com/photos/shanedk/15545424435/in/album-72157646459874723/

Answer (score 2):

I did a terrible version just because I wanted to. I cannot find any graphs that have a shred of scientific accuracy about them. This is drawing on data from the Australian Bureau of Statistics about inequality and the Gini coefficient over time in Australia. Line segments in blue are periods of conservative government rule(Liberal/National parties) while segments in red are periods of left-wing(ish) rule (Labor Party).
[image: Labor vs Liberal parties on Gini Coefficient]